# AddIns.Add statement throwing an Internal Error 51

Tags: vba, excel-addins

I am trying to install addins programmatically (more precisely, it is automated version update on `Workbook_Open` event) but I have run into an issue with the AddIns.Add method, which just "does not work". I copy the desired adding into `C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Addins` and then feed the full filepath to `AddIns.Add`, however the addin is not added, as evidenced by the subsequent statement failing (subscript out of range, the name of the supposedly added addin does not exist).

During the install attempt, the execution simply runs through the `AddIns.Add` without any issue (except the result) but on stepping through, I am getting `Internal error (Error 51)`. I have tried a number of ways to work around that, add `Application.Wait` before and after the `AddIns.Add` to make sure it has sufficient time, putting it into a `Do While Loop` statement to attempt multiple executions, but to no avail.

```
AddIns.Add Filename:=sInstallPath & sFile
AddIns(sAddinFullName).Installed = True
```

Btw this worked until yesterday, when I did a couple codes updates but not even remotely close to this area. I think I had some issues with this in past because the statement was envelopped by   `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`, which I think resolved probably a similar issue but I cannot recall that any more.

Edit: Adding a broader part of the code - a function that does the installation proper and on success, returns `True`.

```
Function InstallAddin(sFullPath, sAddinName) As Boolean    
    Dim oAddin As Object
    Dim bAdded As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Do Until bAdded = True Or i = 10        
        For Each oAddin In AddIns
                If oAddin.Name = sAddinName Then
                    bAdded = True
                    Exit For
                End If
        Next oAddin
    
        If bAdded = False Then
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            AddIns.Add Filename:=sFullPath, CopyFile:=False
            Debug.Print "Attempt " & i
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    If bAdded = True Then
        'disable events to prevent recurrence - installing addin counts as opening its workbook
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        AddIns(sAddinName).Installed = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
        InstallAddin = True
    End If

End Function
```

sFullPath : "C:\Users\Eleshar\Documents\Addins\MyAddin - v.0.25.xlam"

sAddinName : "MyAddin - v.0.25"

The "MyAddin - v.0.25.xlam" file is present in the installation path.

There is a piece of code elsewhere, which ensures that a regular WB is open during this event.

Edit 2: The full functionality of the macro is:

1. On opening the file by a user, offering self-install.
2. On opening the file by a user, checking for previous installed versions, offering self-installation (after which it removes the old versions, including itself).
3. `On Workbook_Open`, checking a Sharepoint repository for any new versions, offering to install the newest one available and removing any older versions including itself.

Edit 3: So I found an interesting thing... `AddIns.Add` does not seem to work when executed from the code (the addin does not get listed in Developer > Addins). However when I type the same exact statement into the immediate window during the execution, it works and then the addin can get installed...

Comment: I am afraid that an ending backslash "\" is missing from `sInstallPath`, or needs to be add in `AddIns.Add Filename:=sInstallPath & "\" &  sFile`

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks, that's not it - it is already part of the ```sInstallPath``` variable.

Comment: Does your code previously check if the add-in to be installed is not already installed? I cannot place here come code. I will put it in an answer. I mean,  a piece of code to make my add-is auto installable when they are open.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not show all your used code, please try the next one. I am using it to auto install the add-ins I design:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim Name As String, tmp As Boolean, n As Boolean, Merk As String
   Name = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(1) '(1)
   On Error Resume Next
   tmp = AddIns(Name).Installed
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
         If Workbooks.Count = 0 Then n = True
             If n Then
                 Workbooks.Add
                 Merk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
             End If
             AddIns.Add FileName:=ThisWorkbook.FullName
             AddIns(Name).Installed = True
             If n Then Workbooks(Merk).Close False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

'(1) it represents the Add-inn title. It can be set programmatically or manual in Properties - Details - Title. When add-in is not open!

Comment: Will look into this. My macro is a bit more complicated since its purpose is:

Comment: @Eleshar If you do  not share it, I am afraid that you cannot be helped... I placed a comment only based on what I could see in your question.

Comment: Indeed, I cannot be helped if I cannot even write a comment right:) My macro does 3 things: 1) self-install on open; 2) on open, checking for previous installed versions and if found, self-installing and removing them; 3) on Workbook_Open, checking a repository for a newer version, if found, installing that and removing any old installed versions including itself. Part of the code posted above.

Comment: @Eleshar I am afraid that the logic of your code is wrong, or you do not understand what  `AddIns(Name).Installed` really does, no offence... It returns **if the add-in is installed**, but not the case, or **it installs the respective add-in**, **IF NOT INSTALLED**. But your code already found it being installed. Let me search for Microsoft documentation about the issue. OK, check [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.addin.installed?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm185076);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) please...

Comment: I added the code to the original question. I understand what it does. My current execution finds a new version of the addin, saves it to a folder, ```.adds``` it into the addin collection, and then ```.installs``` it. Except the ```.Add``` method does not seem to succeed. I do not even get to the ```.Installed = True```

Comment: @Eleshar But, like I said from the beginning, your code does  not check if the add-in is installed... At least, replace `If oAddin.Name = sAddinName Then` with `If oAddin.Name = sAddinName And Not oAddin.Installed Then`. I think you will have the surprise that the add-in is already installed and this is the reason because it cannot be installed (the second time). Then I cannot understand the logic of your code in case of `If bAdded = False`... If it is already installed your code will stay in an infinite loop.

Comment: The addin is not installed. I have "MyAddin - v.0.24" and it is attempting to update to v.0.25. To install an addin, the addin need to be added first into the collection of addins but I am not succeeding in that. The loop you are referrring to is there to prevent getting to the ```Addins("MyAddin").Installed = True```, if the addin is not *added* in the first place (because then the Installed property change fails because calling the addin results in "subscript out of range".

Comment: @Eleshar I cannot get you, sorry... I am not so sure that add-in must "be added first into the collection of addins". **Did you even try the above code I supplied**? I all the times used `AddIns(Name).Installed = True` where `Name` is its **Title**. Of course, its title may also be its name. I tried explaining above what is it about...  I wish you succes in installing it in the way you try!

Comment: ```AddIns(Name).Installed = True``` changes the ```.Installed``` property of an object called ```Name``` in the ```AddIns``` collection. That means that such an object first needs to exist in that collection and if it is not there, it needs to be added there first. In your code, you achieve that by ```AddIns.Add FileName:=ThisWorkbook.FullName```. And *this* is the statement that fails in my code. I can't simply copy-paste your code because in my situation, an installed addin installs *another, different* addin (v.0.24 is installing v.0.25).

Answer (score 0):

So I did not really figure out the issue with `AddIns.Add`, however I worked around that but having the macro directly edit the Excel registry keys to install the add in.

```
Sub AddinInstall(sAddinName As String, ByVal sFullPath As String)
    Dim oShell As Object: Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim sRegKey As String: sRegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\OPEN"
    Dim sSZ As String
    sFullPath = ChrW(34) & sFullPath & ChrW(34)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Do 'loop through registry keys (non-existent key results in error, so errors must be disabled) to find if lower version is installed
        i = i + 1
        sSZ = ""
        sSZ = oShell.RegRead(sRegKey & CStr(i))
        
        If Len(sSZ) > 0 Then
            If sSZ Like "*" & sAddinName & "*" Then
                Debug.Print sSZ
                iIndex = i 'get number at the end of registry key name
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until Len(sSZ) = 0
    
    If iIndex > 0 Then 'previous version installed - overwrite
        oShell.RegWrite sRegKey & CStr(iIndex), sFullPath, "REG_SZ"
    Else 'previous version not found, create new registry key
        oShell.RegWrite sRegKey & CStr(i), sFullPath, "REG_SZ"
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```